# Compile Errors from cstdlib and similar when trying to "make" C++-project on Linux Mint 17.1 64bit (not declared/not a type)

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, std

I am kind of stuck on this.
I just installed a virtual box with Linux Mint on it, set up all sorts of libs/packages I need and am getting errors when trying to "make"

As I need OpenCV for my project I followed these instructions for package installation etc.:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html

Building OpenCV itself worked without any problems which is why the following error codes got me quite surprised...

After using cmake on the project I try to "make" it and get the following errors (just a few examples chosen for clarity - full error log can be found here: http://pastebin.com/Ekn3szTb):

```
    /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:112:1: error: ‘log10’ was not declared in this scope
     __MATHCALL (log10,, (_Mdouble_ __x));
     ^
    /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:112:1: error: ‘__CONCAT’ cannot be used as a function
     __MATHCALL (log10,, (_Mdouble_ __x));
     ^
    /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:112:1: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
     __MATHCALL (log10,, (_Mdouble_ __x));

[...]

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:195:1: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
 __MATHDECL_1 (int,__finite,, (_Mdouble_ __value)) __attribute__ ((__const__));
 ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:196:1: error: ‘__END_NAMESPACE_STD’ does not name a type
 _Mdouble_END_NAMESPACE
 ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h:94:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core_c.h:47,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv/cv.h:63,
                 from /home/appuru/desktop/test/build/include/demo.h:4,

[...]

/usr/include/stdio.h:46:1: error: ‘__BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD’ does not name a type
 __BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD
 ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:49:1: error: ‘__END_NAMESPACE_STD’ does not name a type
 __END_NAMESPACE_STD

[..]

/usr/include/stdio.h:237:20: error: ‘FILE’ was not declared in this scope
 extern int fclose (FILE *__stream);
                    ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:237:26: error: ‘__stream’ was not declared in this scope
 extern int fclose (FILE *__stream);
[...]
```

and so on...

Most if not all errors seem to come from calls through "cv.h" (which is included in my header file) to standard c++ libs.

I've been googling for quite some time now and tried almost everything that seemed related to my problem, yet nothing fixed it.

What am I missing?
I'm new to Linux which is why I'm not quite sure what else I need to look into.. 
Am I missing certain packages or do I need to specify additional things?

/edit:

here's the cmake call:

```
appuru@appuru-VirtualBox ~/desktop/test/build $ cmake ..
jsoncpp_FOUND = 1
jsoncpp_INCLUDES = /usr/local/include/json
jsoncpp_LIBRARIES = /usr/local/lib/libjsoncpp.a
OpenCV_LIBS = opencv_videostab;opencv_video;opencv_ts;opencv_superres;opencv_stitching;opencv_photo;opencv_ocl;opencv_objdetect;opencv_nonfree;opencv_ml;opencv_legacy;opencv_imgproc;opencv_highgui;opencv_gpu;opencv_flann;opencv_features2d;opencv_core;opencv_contrib;opencv_calib3d
OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS = /usr/local/include/opencv;/usr/local/include
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/appuru/desktop/test/build
```

/edit2:

VERBOSE:

```
appuru@appuru-VirtualBox ~/desktop/test/build $ make VERBOSE=1
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/appuru/desktop/test -B/home/appuru/desktop/test/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/appuru/desktop/test/build/CMakeFiles /home/appuru/desktop/test/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory »/home/appuru/desktop/test/build« 
make -f CMakeFiles/test.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/test.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory »/home/appuru/desktop/test/build« 
cd /home/appuru/desktop/test/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/appuru/desktop/test /home/appuru/desktop/test /home/appuru/desktop/test/build /home/appuru/desktop/test/build /home/appuru/desktop/test/build/CMakeFiles/test.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Quitting directory »/home/appuru/desktop/test/build« 
make -f CMakeFiles/test.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/test.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory »/home/appuru/desktop/test/build« 
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/appuru/desktop/test/build/CMakeFiles 1
[ 11%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/src/testDetector.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++    -O3 -DNDEBUG -I/home/appuru/desktop/test/build/include -I/home/appuru/desktop/test/include -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/json    -o CMakeFiles/test.dir/src/testDetector.cpp.o -c /home/appuru/desktop/test/src/testDetector.cpp
```

after that it's just like what I posted before..?

CMakeLists.txt:

```
    CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED (VERSION 2.8)



    PROJECT (test)


    SET (LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib")
    SET (EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin")


    # The version number
    SET (test_VERSION_MAJOR 1)
    SET (test_VERSION_MINOR 0)
    SET (DEBUG false)


    # configure a header file to pass some of the CMake settings to the source code
    CONFIGURE_FILE (
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/testConfig.h.in"
        "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/include/testConfig.h"
    )


    FILE(GLOB INCLUDES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.h")
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/include")
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")


    SET (CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
    FIND_PACKAGE (OpenCV REQUIRED)
    FIND_PACKAGE (jsoncpp REQUIRED)


    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ("${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ("${jsoncpp_INCLUDES}")


FILE (GLOB SOURCES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.c*")
SET (SOURCES ${SOURCES})


SET (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
ADD_LIBRARY (test STATIC ${SOURCES} ${INCLUDES})
FILE(COPY ${INCLUDES} DESTINATION "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/include")

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (test ${OpenCV_LIBS})
MESSAGE ("OpenCV_LIBS = ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
MESSAGE ("OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS = ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (test ${jsoncpp_LIBS})

INSTALL (TARGETS test ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib LIBRARY DESTINATION lib COMPONENT library)
INSTALL (FILES ${INCLUDES} DESTINATION include/test)


#PROJECT (testDemo)

FILE (GLOB MARKERC_SRC "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/tools/testDemo.cpp")
SET (MARKER_SRC ${MARKERC_SRC})
ADD_EXECUTABLE (testDemo ${MARKER_SRC})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (testDemo ${OpenCV_LIBS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (testDemo ${jsoncpp_LIBS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (testDemo ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}/libtest.a)
```

Comment: you probably should show us your cmake

Comment: thought so but as it shows nothing of significance I refrained from doing so. sec, editing it in.

Comment: show the gcc invocation that failed, with all the command line arguments. (CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE or --trace).

Comment: @Appuru, as you have problems with building, show us the file, that is the base of your building -- CMakeLists etc.

Comment: Also can you compile and run a "hello world" c  or c++ program?

Comment: added what i got from verbose and the current cmakelists.the program itself compiles perfectly on a friends computer. it's probably something super simple I forgot to setup or so :/ running that linux virtual box on windows btw.  I'll try to compile/run a hello world program and post here again then

Comment: cmake, make and make install of a simple hello world program in c++ works without problems.

Comment: the version is 4.8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting up linux 2 more times and still having the same error at different stages of building my project I found the reason for it.

jsoncpp uses a header named features.h while the standard c++ libs includes another features.h as well.

For whatever reason it worked for everyone else but made my computer pick the wrong header file when building the libraries. I already searched this error before and found that it was fixed by the jsoncpp guys, guess not for all possible setups though.

I now use the amalgamated version of jsoncpp and don't link it with cmake anymore.

Comment: Indeed, there is no detector in the compiler against such mistakes. I have been stuck 2 days. (and it's not json, it's my own project). Thanks for the help.

Comment: In fact, it's not the filename that is a problem, but the include guardian: `_FEATURES_H` Rename it and pass.